# bootstrap panel heading - aligning controls horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align the controls in bootstrap panel-heading and it is not aligning horizontally. See the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/23/

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="DataRow" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#DataRow" href="#CollapseData" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="CollapseData">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
                                </a>
                                Data</h3>
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-md-10">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs disabled" id="DownloadBtn" type="button" title="Download all data"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbspDownload</button>
                        </div>               
                    </div>
                <div id="CollapseData" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-inline col-sm-12 move-down-sm">
                           Controls will be displayed here
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-horizontal col-sm-12 move-down-sm">
                           Controls will be displayed here
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-inline col-sm-12 move-down-sm">
                            Controls will be displayed here
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="SaveChangesBtn" type="button" title="Save the changes"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbspSave Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What is the best way to align controls horizontally in panel-heading without overwriting bootstrap classes?

Expectation:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup needs to be changed a bit:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/24/)

```
<div id="DataRow" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#DataRow" href="#CollapseData" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="CollapseData">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
                </a>
                Data
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs disabled" id="DownloadBtn" type="button" title="Download all data"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbspDownload</button>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="CollapseData" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-inline col-sm-12 move-down-sm">
                    Controls will be displayed here
                </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal col-sm-12 move-down-sm">
                    Controls will be displayed here
                </div>
                <div class="form-inline col-sm-12 move-down-sm">
                    Controls will be displayed here
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="SaveChangesBtn" type="button" title="Save the changes"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbspSave Changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I removed the `col-*-2` and `col-*-10` from the `panel-heading`, and surrounded the `<a>` , `Data` and `<button>` in the same `<h3 class="panel-title">` element. If you want the button to be on the right hand side, add a `<span class="pull-right">` around `<button class="btn btn-danger" ...>` like so:

```
<span class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs disabled" id="DownloadBtn" type="button" title="Download all data">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        &nbsp;Download
    </button>
</span>
```

[JSFiddle Alternative](https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/25/)

Answer (score 1):

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/99x50s2s/26/)

```
<div class="panel-heading">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Data
            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#DataRow" href="#CollapseData" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="CollapseData">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs disabled" id="DownloadBtn" type="button" title="Download all data"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbspDownload</button>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```